# Cannot connect to dlib webserver remotely, localhost does work

Tags: javascript, c++, ajax

I am currently developing a html/javascript frontend with a c++ backend doing all the calculations. Both are connected via an integrated small dlib webserver that handles all the requests. The frontend requests data like this:

```
pop=$.ajax({ //load Population array of 90
        type:"POST",
        url: "Pop90",
        async:false
        });
    eval(pop.responseText);
```

The webserver returns then a large array (length around 4 000 000) in a single string.
This works perfectly if I connect via localhost, but I cannot access the server remotely on another computer. The browser just loads a while and then times out, but I can see all the requests on the server. The server throws an error: dlib.server_http: http field from client is too long. But the http request from the client should not be to big, the actual post from the server is.
Thx a lot in advance!
To elaborate a bit more. I just tested the page in firefox, which doesn't work even via localhost. The error console sais the array initializer, which is the respinse string of the webserver and it goes like this, but with like 4 million entries:

```
"ar=[-99999, -99999, ...]"
```

The webserver class that handles the request looks like this:

```
    class web_server : public server_http
{
    vector<vector<double>> pop90;
    vector<vector<double>> pop95;
    vector<vector<double>> pop00;
    public: web_server::web_server()
        {
        cout<<"init...";
        loadArray("data/raw/afp90g.asc", &pop90);
        cout<<" 90 loaded...";
        loadArray("data/raw/afp95g.asc", &pop95);
        cout<<" 95 loaded...";
        loadArray("data/raw/afp00g.asc", &pop00);
        cout<<" 00 loaded...";
        cout<<"ready!"<<endl;
        }
    const std::string on_request (const incoming_things& incoming, outgoing_things& outgoing)
        {
        cout<<"---------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<incoming.path<<endl;
        ostringstream sout;
        sout<<get_file_contents("Seite.html");
        cout<<"content type: "<<incoming.content_type<<endl;
        cout<<"request type: "<<incoming.request_type<<endl;
        string filename=incoming.path.substr(1,incoming.path.length()); 
        if (incoming.path.substr(0,1) == "/" && incoming.path.length()>1)
            {
            if (incoming.path=="/css/Style.css") outgoing.headers["Content-Type"] == "text/css";
            if (incoming.path.substr(0,8)=="/Pop90") return parseArray(pop90);
            if (incoming.path.substr(0,8)=="/Pop95") return parseArray(pop95);
            if (incoming.path.substr(0,8)=="/Pop00") return parseArray(pop00);
            return get_file_contents(filename.c_str());
            }
        return sout.str();
        }
};
```

Ok, so I tinkered a bit with the server_http.cpp file to create a full dump of the incoming stream. It seams as though there are randomly -1 values (EOF) in between perfectly fine http messages as long as is connect locally. If I connect remotely via my actual ip theres only -1 values coming in. I deactivated my firewall/antivirus. Port forwarding should be ok. I still habe no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I've got it figured out. Apparently my router misses a feature called NAT loopback. So my webserver does work remotely, i'ts just not accessible from within the LAN network.

Source is in German:http://forum.telekom.de/foren/read/service/dsl-festnetz/speedports/speedport-700er-serie/w723v-typ-b-portweiterleitung-funktioniert-nicht-mehr,510,8862346,page=2.html

Answer (score 1):

To prevent clients from flooding the server and exhausting its memory, dlib's web server has a limit on the length of HTTP headers and the query path string.  Specifically, it requires each to be individually less than 16KB in length and if the client tries to send more than that it gives the "http field from client is too long" error message you are seeing.

So you must be somehow generating a really long path or maybe you are sending back a very large header (perhaps from a big cookie you are creating?).  You can change the 16KB limit to something else by editing line 129 in dlib/server/server_http.cpp.  It would be better if this was settable by calling a member function so (since I'm the author of dlib :) ) I'll make that a feature in the next release.

But in any event, it's surprising that you are hitting the 16KB limit since that's really a pretty big limit considering the usual lengths of the path string and HTTP headers.  So there might be something else going on in your HTTP client code.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Even though I don't think thats part of the real problem, since the error is thrown when connecting per localhost as well and the page works fine, I managed to reproduce it reliably. If Javascript loads html content into a div element via: '$("#test").load("content/config.html");' it works directly, but shortly after around 10 seconds the error is thrown. I'll post my c++ code in the original question.

Comment: Your code looks fine.  I would put a print statement at the throw site (dlib/server/server_http.cpp line 140) and print the string that has gotten to be 16KB long and see what it is.

Comment: Excellent idea! I tried to cout<< the buffer variable as well as its size, turns out it is empty. The error is thrown because of the other condition (in.peek() == EOF)

Comment: Well, the HTTP headers are supposed to be terminated with a \r\n sequence.  So if that isn't being sent before the end of the connection (EOF) then something is wrong with how the HTTP POST is being constructed.

Comment: Yea, but  '$("#test").load("content/config.html");" is pretty simple and should not cause any problems (Which, in a way, it doesn't since it works fine). Right now I'll just comment the throw out, so it won't bother me anymore. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I investigated further and updated the OP, not sure if you get a message so I'm also commenting here. Would it be any help if I provided the http dumps? Is there a way to upload textfiles here?

Comment: At this point, you should probably just email me the dumps :)